# How can I create a collection of items that

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

Let me try to explain the design pattern I'm looking to implement. I have a `Queue<Item>` or some other collection of `Item`s that needs to be processed by some method

```
static void Process(Item item) 
{
   // ... 
}
```

They can be processed synchronously or asynchronously.

This queue will be getting items added to it periodically, because I have some method like

```
static void AddWorkToQueue()
{
   // ... 
}
```

that gets run on a timer

```
timer.Elapsed += AddWorkToQueue();
```

So what I need is some type "continuous `while` loop" that stops whenever the queue is empty.

How can I use C#.NET to do this in the best way? Are there any built-in libraries for solving this type of problem?

Comment: What's wrong with what you've got? Seems like `Queue<T>` with `Enqueue` and `Dequeue` on separate timers is fine, you can check the `Count` to see if there are items to process.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom queue class and change it's listener:

```
public class CustomQueue : Queue<object>
{
    public event EventHandler FirstItemInserted;

    protected virtual void OnFirstItemInserted()
    {
        FirstItemInserted?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    //Modified Enqueue method.
    public new void Enqueue(object obj)
    {
        //Call the listener every time an item is inserted into the empty queue.
        if (Count == 0)
        {
            base.Enqueue(obj);
            OnFirstItemInserted();
        }
        else
            base.Enqueue(obj);
    }
}
```

The "Enqueue" method was changed to call the listener after each first insert.
All you'll need to do is to call a method to consume each item of your queue as long as there are items to dequeue.

```
class MyProgram
{
    private static CustomQueue MyQueue;

    public MyProgram()
    {
        MyQueue = new CustomQueue();
        MyQueue.FirstItemInserted += ConsumeQueue;

       //Activate timer...
    }

    private static void ConsumeQueue(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        object item;

        while (MyQueue.Count > 0)
        {
            item = MyQueue.Dequeue();
            //Do something...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `BufferBlock<Item>` from TPL DataFlow (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160414(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow;

static void AddWorkToQueue()
{
  queue.Send(new Item());
}

static async void MainLoop()
{
  while (true) // may be you need some cancellation token to trigger end of processing
  {
     var item = await queue.ReceiveAsync();
     ProcessItem(item);
  }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't a `ConcurrentQueue` be more appropriate?

Comment: How would you implement it with `ConcurrentQueue`? You need to handle case when queue became empty for some time and you need to wait when new item will arrive. Of course you can implement it manually (using some synchronization primitives) but you can also use built-in implementation

Comment: Observe the result of `TryDequeue`, when it returns false then your process stops.

Comment: I think you shouldn't stop. You should wait when next item will be added

Comment: I agree with you, it was OP who asked it to stop. Personally I'd wrap ConcurrentQueue and expose an event for Enqueue that I could use to start the Dequeue timer again.